# Ошибка при сборке Firefox?

Tags: c++, firefox

Ошибка при сборке Firefox.
Все делал по инструкции с сайта [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5/Simple_Firefox_build)

1. Скачал исходники
2. Создал и заполнил файл конфига
3. Попытался собрать командой( `./mach build`)
   И вылетает ошибка(скрин ниже).
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скрине код питонячий. Не ясно причём тут c++.

Comment: Firefox написан на C++

Comment: Ошибка никак не связана с C++.

Comment: А можете весь текст ошибки показать?

Comment: а это и есть вся ошибка. У меня такое месяц назад случалось с thunderbird, просто даже в 2020 не все знают, что бывают кириллические кодировки и то, что ascii, latin-1 и utf-8 в первых 128 совпадают и не ругаются.

Comment: Так что делать-то?